# Keras Memory Network implementation on Babi Dataset

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am going through the following code of memory network using keras on Babi dataset -

```
            '''Trains a memory network on the bAbI dataset.
            References:
            - Jason Weston, Antoine Bordes, Sumit Chopra, Tomas Mikolov, Alexander M. Rush,
              "Towards AI-Complete Question Answering: A Set of Prerequisite Toy Tasks",
              http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.05698
            - Sainbayar Sukhbaatar, Arthur Szlam, Jason Weston, Rob Fergus,
              "End-To-End Memory Networks",
              http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08895
            Reaches 98.6% accuracy on task 'single_supporting_fact_10k' after 120 epochs.
            Time per epoch: 3s on CPU (core i7).
            '''
            from __future__ import print_function

            from keras.models import Sequential, Model
            from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
            from keras.layers import Input, Activation, Dense, Permute, Dropout, add, dot, concatenate
            from keras.layers import LSTM
            from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
            from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
            from functools import reduce
            import tarfile
            import numpy as np
            import re


            def tokenize(sent):
                '''Return the tokens of a sentence including punctuation.
                >>> tokenize('Bob dropped the apple. Where is the apple?')
                ['Bob', 'dropped', 'the', 'apple', '.', 'Where', 'is', 'the', 'apple', '?']
                '''
                return [x.strip() for x in re.split('(\W+)?', sent) if x.strip()]


            def parse_stories(lines, only_supporting=False):
                '''Parse stories provided in the bAbi tasks format
                If only_supporting is true, only the sentences
                that support the answer are kept.
                '''
                data = []
                story = []
                for line in lines:
                    line = line.decode('utf-8').strip()
                    nid, line = line.split(' ', 1)
                    nid = int(nid)
                    if nid == 1:
                        story = []
                    if '\t' in line:
                        q, a, supporting = line.split('\t')
                        q = tokenize(q)
                        substory = None
                        if only_supporting:
                            # Only select the related substory
                            supporting = map(int, supporting.split())
                            substory = [story[i - 1] for i in supporting]
                        else:
                            # Provide all the substories
                            substory = [x for x in story if x]
                        data.append((substory, q, a))
                        story.append('')
                    else:
                        sent = tokenize(line)
                        story.append(sent)
                return data


            def get_stories(f, only_supporting=False, max_length=None):
                '''Given a file name, read the file,
                retrieve the stories,
                and then convert the sentences into a single story.
                If max_length is supplied,
                any stories longer than max_length tokens will be discarded.
                '''
                data = parse_stories(f.readlines(), only_supporting=only_supporting)
                flatten = lambda data: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, data)
                data = [(flatten(story), q, answer) for story, q, answer in data if not max_length or len(flatten(story)) < max_length]
                return data


            def vectorize_stories(data, word_idx, story_maxlen, query_maxlen):
                X = []
                Xq = []
                Y = []
                for story, query, answer in data:
                    x = [word_idx[w] for w in story]
                    xq = [word_idx[w] for w in query]
                    # let's not forget that index 0 is reserved
                    y = np.zeros(len(word_idx) + 1)
                    y[word_idx[answer]] = 1
                    X.append(x)
                    Xq.append(xq)
                    Y.append(y)
                return (pad_sequences(X, maxlen=story_maxlen),
                        pad_sequences(Xq, maxlen=query_maxlen), np.array(Y))

            try:
                path = get_file('babi-tasks-v1-2.tar.gz', origin='https://s3.amazonaws.com/text-datasets/babi_tasks_1-20_v1-2.tar.gz')
            except:
                print('Error downloading dataset, please download it manually:\n'
                      '$ wget http://www.thespermwhale.com/jaseweston/babi/tasks_1-20_v1-2.tar.gz\n'
                      '$ mv tasks_1-20_v1-2.tar.gz ~/.keras/datasets/babi-tasks-v1-2.tar.gz')
                raise
            tar = tarfile.open(path)

            challenges = {
                # QA1 with 10,000 samples
                'single_supporting_fact_10k': 'tasks_1-20_v1-2/en-10k/qa1_single-supporting-fact_{}.txt',
                # QA2 with 10,000 samples
                'two_supporting_facts_10k': 'tasks_1-20_v1-2/en-10k/qa2_two-supporting-facts_{}.txt',
            }
            challenge_type = 'single_supporting_fact_10k'
            challenge = challenges[challenge_type]

            print('Extracting stories for the challenge:', challenge_type)
            train_stories = get_stories(tar.extractfile(challenge.format('train')))
            test_stories = get_stories(tar.extractfile(challenge.format('test')))

            vocab = set()
            for story, q, answer in train_stories + test_stories:
                vocab |= set(story + q + [answer])
            vocab = sorted(vocab)

            # Reserve 0 for masking via pad_sequences
            vocab_size = len(vocab) + 1
            story_maxlen = max(map(len, (x for x, _, _ in train_stories + test_stories)))
            query_maxlen = max(map(len, (x for _, x, _ in train_stories + test_stories)))

            print('-')
            print('Vocab size:', vocab_size, 'unique words')
            print('Story max length:', story_maxlen, 'words')
            print('Query max length:', query_maxlen, 'words')
            print('Number of training stories:', len(train_stories))
            print('Number of test stories:', len(test_stories))
            print('-')
            print('Here\'s what a "story" tuple looks like (input, query, answer):')
            print(train_stories[0])
            print('-')
            print('Vectorizing the word sequences...')

            word_idx = dict((c, i + 1) for i, c in enumerate(vocab))
            inputs_train, queries_train, answers_train = vectorize_stories(train_stories,
                                                                           word_idx,
                                                                           story_maxlen,
                                                                           query_maxlen)
            inputs_test, queries_test, answers_test = vectorize_stories(test_stories,
                                                                        word_idx,
                                                                        story_maxlen,
                                                                        query_maxlen)

            print('-')
            print('inputs: integer tensor of shape (samples, max_length)')
            print('inputs_train shape:', inputs_train.shape)
            print('inputs_test shape:', inputs_test.shape)
            print('-')
            print('queries: integer tensor of shape (samples, max_length)')
            print('queries_train shape:', queries_train.shape)
            print('queries_test shape:', queries_test.shape)
            print('-')
            print('answers: binary (1 or 0) tensor of shape (samples, vocab_size)')
            print('answers_train shape:', answers_train.shape)
            print('answers_test shape:', answers_test.shape)
            print('-')
            print('Compiling...')

            # placeholders
            input_sequence = Input((story_maxlen,))
            question = Input((query_maxlen,))

            # encoders
            # embed the input sequence into a sequence of vectors
            input_encoder_m = Sequential()
            input_encoder_m.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                                          output_dim=64))
            input_encoder_m.add(Dropout(0.3))
            # output: (samples, story_maxlen, embedding_dim)

            # embed the input into a sequence of vectors of size query_maxlen
            input_encoder_c = Sequential()
            input_encoder_c.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                                          output_dim=query_maxlen))
            input_encoder_c.add(Dropout(0.3))
            # output: (samples, story_maxlen, query_maxlen)

            # embed the question into a sequence of vectors
            question_encoder = Sequential()
            question_encoder.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                                           output_dim=64,
                                           input_length=query_maxlen))
            question_encoder.add(Dropout(0.3))
            # output: (samples, query_maxlen, embedding_dim)

            # encode input sequence and questions (which are indices)
            # to sequences of dense vectors
            input_encoded_m = input_encoder_m(input_sequence)
            input_encoded_c = input_encoder_c(input_sequence)
            question_encoded = question_encoder(question)

            # compute a 'match' between the first input vector sequence
            # and the question vector sequence
            # shape: `(samples, story_maxlen, query_maxlen)`
            match = dot([input_encoded_m, question_encoded], axes=(2, 2))
            match = Activation('softmax')(match)

            # add the match matrix with the second input vector sequence
            response = add([match, input_encoded_c])  # (samples, story_maxlen, query_maxlen)
            response = Permute((2, 1))(response)  # (samples, query_maxlen, story_maxlen)

            # concatenate the match matrix with the question vector sequence
            answer = concatenate([response, question_encoded])

            # the original paper uses a matrix multiplication for this reduction step.
            # we choose to use a RNN instead.
            answer = LSTM(32)(answer)  # (samples, 32)

            # one regularization layer -- more would probably be needed.
            answer = Dropout(0.3)(answer)
            answer = Dense(vocab_size)(answer)  # (samples, vocab_size)
            # we output a probability distribution over the vocabulary
            answer = Activation('softmax')(answer)

            # build the final model
            model = Model([input_sequence, question], answer)
            model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                          metrics=['accuracy'])

            # train
            model.fit([inputs_train, queries_train], answers_train,
                      batch_size=32,
                      epochs=120,
                      validation_data=([inputs_test, queries_test], answers_test))
```

This is what my understanding is for the model creation part -

After creating dense vectors of story and question part with below code -

```
            input_encoded_m = input_encoder_m(input_sequence)
            input_encoded_c = input_encoder_c(input_sequence)
            question_encoded = question_encoder(question)
```

outputs will have below shapes

input_encoded_m will have shape - **samples, story_maxlen, query_maxlen**
input_encoded_c will have shape - **samples, story_maxlen, query_maxlen**
question_encoded will have shape - **samples, query_maxlen, embedding_dim**

input_encoded_m and input_encoded_c have same input embedded in different dimensions i.e. (68 and 4). and question_encoded will have question embedded.

now below part matches the word in story and question and applies softmax activation on the output which means matching words are identified -

```
            match = dot([input_encoded_m, question_encoded], axes=(2, 2))
            match = Activation('softmax')(match)
```

I am not clear about why differently embedded same input vector is being added to the matched matrix from above step. Comment says "Second input vector" but we are not dealing with 2nd input yet..Not able to understand this, Any help??? 
                # add the match matrix with the second input vector sequence
                response = add([match, input_encoded_c])  # (samples, story_maxlen, query_maxlen)

Also what permuting the output of above step does in this context - 
                response = Permute((2, 1))(response)  # (samples, query_maxlen, story_maxlen)

this is just concatenating the story from above part with question for LSTM layer? please correct if my understanding is wrong here -

```
            # concatenate the match matrix with the question vector sequence
            answer = concatenate([response, question_encoded])
```

I coudn't find any intuitive explanation of this anywhere so posting here.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, `match` variable doesn't only identify matched words, it gives a probability distribution on the input. These can be seen as weights for each input sentence.

The input sequence is embedded by using two different matrices whose results are `input_encoded_c` and `input_encoded_m` in the code. Using the 1st embedding, we find the match weights. Then applying weights to the 2nd embedded vectors we find the answer. It won't be logical to apply the weights to the same vectors where we calculated them.

Then comes [Permute](https://keras.io/layers/core/#permute). To generate the answer, 
we add the query to the `response`, to have the same dimensions we permute the dimensions of the response.

In paper [End-to-End Memory Network](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.08895.pdf) , if you read section 2.1, it will help you to understand.